# Input value synchronized from another input using jQuery event is not available during form submission

Tags: html, jquery, validation, input, form-submit

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#StaffNumber').on('keyup', function () {
        var staffNo = $(this).val();
        $('#Username').val('EMP' + staffNo);
    });

});
```

Here **Username** input is filled with new value, But that value is not available when submitting form. Also I have required field validation on **Username**, Which also fires on submit even after it filled with value in jQuery event. How can I retain the value of **Username**?

`$('#StaffNumber').on('input', function () {...});`

`$('#StaffNumber').on('keyup paste', function () {...});`

I tried the above events also, But still the value is not retained!

> **Edit:** By preventing default submission, **Username** value can be retained.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#StaffNumber').keyup(function() {
    $('#Username').val('EMP' + $('#StaffNumber').val());
  });

});

document.getElementById('testForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var staffNumber = document.getElementById('StaffNumber').value;
  var username = document.getElementById('Username').value;

  console.log('Submitted Form Values: Staff#:' + staffNumber + ' Username:' + username);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jQuery input synch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="testForm">
    <label for="StaffNumber">Staff#</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="StaffNumber" name="StaffNumber" value=""><br>
    <label for="Username">Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="Username" name="Username" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why isn't the Username available when submitting the form? Are you sure the field is inside the `<form>`?

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question, and not just snippets that lack context.

Comment: Validation doesn't care whether the field was filled in by hand or from JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the field is inside the form. Actually the **Username** set to read-only and it is filled when user inputting in **StaffNumber** field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the event binding code is inside $(document).ready(). Use the change event instead of keyup for #StaffNumber input field. Combine both keyup and change events if needed. Check for custom form submission handling and prevent the default form submission behavior. Verify the form validation code to recognize the updated value of Username.

Comment: Edited the question by preventing the default and works as expected. I think the required field validation fires because jQuery validator plugin by default, only performs validation when the user interacts with the form elements directly.